# how to map object data type

Tags: c#, nhibernate

My domain object have entity of object data type

```
public virtual object ProviderUserKey {get; set;}
```

I'm using mapping by code approach so I tried to map like any other data type like this

```
Property(x => x.ProviderUserKey);
```

but I'm getting this error

> {"property mapping has wrong number of columns:
>   Model.Account.ProviderUserKey type: Object"}

so how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use object datatypes in your entity classes. `Nhibernate` does'nt know how to map object into a valid db type.

Instead of casting your `ProviderUserKey` to `Guid` or whatever it is change it and use explicit datatype like `Guid ProviderUserKey`.